# How to set Hadoop fs.s3a.acl.default on AWS EMR?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I have a map-reduce application running on AWS EMR that writes some output to a different (aws account) s3 bucket. I have the permission setup and the job can write to the external bucket, but the owner is still the `root` from the account where the Hadoop job is running. I would like to change this to the external account that owns the bucket.

I found I can set `fs.s3a.acl.default` to `bucket-owner-full-control`, however that doesn't seem like working. This is what I am doing:

```
conf.set("fs.s3a.acl.default", "bucket-owner-full-control");
FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(URI.create(s3Path), conf);
FSDataOutputStream fsDataOutputStream = fileSystem.create(new Path(filePath));
PrintWriter writer  = new PrintWriter(fsDataOutputStream);
writer.write(contentAsString);
writer.close();
fsDataOutputStream.close();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: for sure thats the property you need to send is there any exception ?

Comment: no exception, but the owner is still the writing account, not the account that holds the bucket.

Comment: just do one thing print all the props like this `for (Entry<String, String> entry: conf) {
      System.out.printf("%s=%s\n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }`

Comment: [aws-hadoop](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.7/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html) also confirns that this is the right prop. I think some where else its hitting

Comment: Thanks, let me try seeing the props.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
conf.set("fs.s3a.acl.default", "bucket-owner-full-control");
```

is the right property you are setting.

As this the property in core-site.xml to give full control to bucket owner.

```
<property>
  <name>fs.s3a.acl.default</name>
  <description>Set a canned ACL for newly created and copied objects. Value may be private,
     public-read, public-read-write, authenticated-read, log-delivery-write,
     bucket-owner-read, or bucket-owner-full-control.</description>
</property>
```

***BucketOwnerFullControl***

```
    Specifies that the owner of the bucket is granted Permission.FullControl. The owner of the bucket is not necessarily the same as the owner of the object.
```

I recommend to set `fs.s3.canned.acl` also to value  `BucketOwnerFullControl`

For debugging you can use the below snippet to understand what parameters are actually passing..

```
for (Entry<String, String> entry: conf) {
      System.out.printf("%s=%s\n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
```

For testing purpose do this command with command line

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/source/dummyfile.txt s3://bucket/target/dummyfile.txt --sse --acl bucket-owner-full-control
```

If this works then through api also it will.

#### Bonus point with Spark , useful for spark scala users:

For Spark to access the s3 file system and set the proper configurations like the below example...

```
val hadoopConf = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
    hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.fast.upload","true")
    hadoopConf.set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version","2")
    hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithm", "AES256")
    hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.canned.acl","BucketOwnerFullControl")
    hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.acl.default","BucketOwnerFullControl")
```

Comment: Thank you, looks like `fs.s3.canned.acl` to `BucketOwnerFullControl` did the trick! It is weird that one requires `bucket-owner-full-control` while the other `BucketOwnerFullControl`

Comment: drop the fs.s3a.impl line if you are trying to give help for others; that's just a stack overflow superstition which is not actually needed. thx

Answer (score 3):

If you are using EMR then you have to use the AWS team's S3 connector, with "s3://" URLs and use their documented configuration options. They don't support the apache one, so any option with "fs.s3a" at the beginning isn't going to have any effect whatsoever.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-s3-acls.html

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in answer by Stevel, For EMR with pyspark use this

```
sc=spark.sparkContext
hadoop_conf=sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3.canned.acl","BucketOwnerFullControl")
```

Canned ACL  Description

BucketOwnerFullControl  Specifies that the owner of the bucket is granted
Permission.FullControl. The owner of the bucket is not necessarily
the same as the owner of the object.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-s3-acls.html